# Vuetify Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vuetify.js

While trying to get material icons to load on my Vuetify project (with Webpack and Apollo) I am unable to get my app to display at all.

I followed the installation instructions from Vuetify for webpack, but am getting an error

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined
    at Function.Vue.use (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5106)
    at eval (vuetify.js?402c:12)
    at Module../src/plugins/vuetify.js (app.js:1253)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (main.js:15)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1241)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:1338)
```

Which seems to indicate to me that the issue lies in my `src/plugins/vuetify.js` with the `Vue.use(Vuetify)` line.  However, I can't determine why Vuetify is unable to be installed(?) because I am importing it in the file.

`src/plugins/vuetify.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import {
    Vuetify,
    VApp,
    VCard,
    VIcon,
    /* other imports ... */
} from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const opts = {
    components: {
        VApp,
        VCard,
        VIcon,
        /* other imports */
    },
    icons: {
        iconfont: 'mdi', // default - only for display purposes
    },
}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

`src/main.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import apolloProvider from './vue-apollo'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  apolloProvider: apolloProvider,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

As I understand it, `Vue.use(Vuetify)` in `src/plugins/vuetify.js` is instructing Vue to install/utilize Vuetify, which is coming from `'vuetify'` (which I have confirmed is installed in node_modules).  Then options are defined, like specifying icon set and any components that will be used, and then Vuetify is instantiated with those options and passed outwards through `export default new Vuetify(opts)`.

This exported Vuetify is then accessed in `main.js` by importing it from `@/plugins/vuetify`.  I believe the `@` is a shortcut for webpack that will tell webpack to resolve the alias to the `src` folder.  Since `vuetify` is provided as the alias for the import, I then pass it into the Vue instantiation.  Does all of that seem right?

Also I have a `babel.config.js` with very little content, though I don't expect that to be related to my issue.

Now, on to the question of why isn't this working and how do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing Vuetify as separate components.
Please try to import Vuetify class directly:

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi', // default - only for display purposes
  },
})
```

[link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#material-design-icons)

And thus, you will import entire Vuetify class with **install** function set as:
 `Vuetify.install = install;`

Also, for optimal bundle size, consider to use [treeshaking for Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#vuetify-loader).
As they say:

```
"In order to use treeshaking, you must import Vuetify from vuetify/lib."
and
"Treeshaking will only work with Webpack 4 in production mode.
This is automatic when using Vue CLI."
```

Comment: Thanks.  This solved the initial problem.

Now I am getting an error: `Syntax Error: SassError: Expected newline.`, which prompted me to remove my css-loader and sass-loader from my vue.config.js.  For whatever reason, I am still unable to load in material icons.  Which is the whole reason why I started to try and reconfigure the project in this way.

Comment: @JoeHoward Vue CLI should do tree-shaking automatically, so if you're using CLI, please try to replace the import line with `import Vuetify from 'vuetify'`. Maybe you'll succeed with just that.