# Vue runtime error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'install')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am getting this error when trying to load my app in the browser. The build runs fine, without any errors. But when I try to load the app I get a blank page and this single error in the console:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:5106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'install')
```

I have seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66145169/vuetify-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-install-of-undefined) but it doesn't address my issue because my `vuetify.js` already looks ok:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import { preset } from 'vue-cli-plugin-vuetify-preset-fortnightly/preset';

Vue.use(Vuetify);
 
export default new Vuetify({
    preset,
    theme: {
        dark: false,
        default: 'light'
    }
});
```

If anyone can help out fixing this I'd much appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I have just seen the following after following one of the console links to a file called `vue.runtime.esm.js`.
In the dev console there is a red squiggle line under the  `.install === 'function'` part of the code.

```
 // additional parameters
    var args = toArray(arguments, 1);
    args.unshift(this);
    if (typeof plugin.install === 'function') {
      plugin.install.apply(plugin, args);
    } else if (typeof plugin === 'function') {
      plugin.apply(null, args);
    }
```

Comment: looks to me like you are doing it right, not super helpful I know.  The error implies that `Vue.use` was called with something `undefined`.  Try adding a `console.log('Vuetify',Vuetify)` before the `Vue.use` and see what you get.

Comment: or.. is this all of your code?  Are you calling `Vue.use` anywhere else?

Comment: @EuanSmith thanks for the response. I tried addng the `console.log` and now I get this error `Syntax Error: Error: error while parsing tsconfig.json` when trying to build the project.

Comment: @EuanSmith  to answer your quesiton, yes, `Vue.use` is being called in several files including `main.ts`, `router/index.ts`, and `store.ts`.

Comment: And I presume you've made no inadvertant change to tsconfig.json?  json is quite picky, I've certainly had a stray keystroke cause a headache before.  I can't think of any way in which a console.log could cause that particular error, although of course do remove it again to see if that error goes away.

Comment: To me it looks like the above code is correct (at least it is exactly according to the various source guides), and that it is more likely a different `Vue.use` causing the problem. Can you share the other places you are calling Vue.use?

Comment: Finally, if you have any more of a call stack, that would also help.  Anything to trace back to which Vue.use is causing the problem.

Comment: @EuanSmith OK, I was recently working with the `tsconfig`. I had some other issues and changed it, but the changes didn't resolve the other problem so I reverted to the original `tsconfig`..or so I thought. Now that I look at it there is a red error squiggle at the very first `{` of the `tsconfig` and on hover it says `No inputs were found in config file`, followed by a bunch of file paths.

Comment: I'm going to have to bow out - late here in the UK.  Good luck hunting.  for the tsconfig bug try [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211566/tsconfig-json-buildno-inputs-were-found-in-config-file)

Comment: @EuanSmith now worries, I understand the time diff. I'm in Canada ;D Thanks for the input. I really appreciate it!